# Ajax throbber in SEDE is 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, data-explorer

Minor bug: When executing a query in SEDE, the throbber looks like it's gone AWOL: 
http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/ajax-loader.gif

Answer (score 3):

SO has changed to use [progress-dots.gif](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/img/progress-dots.gif) instead - I guess SEDE hasn't updated yet.

By the way SEDE is FOSS ([here are the repos](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/)), so you might be able to contribute a patch yourself :)

[Here's a list of places that need  replacing.](http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=ajax-loader+package%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fstack-exchange-data-explorer%5C.googlecode%5C.com&origq=ajax-loader&btnG=Search+Trunk)

Answer (score 3):

Good catch.

I've [fixed](http://code.google.com/r/jseigelis-test/source/detail?r=d8b74bd9e807e032a7c63928e8b85386633cce59) this in the repository and it will go live the next time @waffles does a merge & deploy.

Comment: I'm so happy we left azure .. that whole process only took a minute .. change should be live now

Comment: Does that mean "confirmed" it's deployed? Cos it's not throbbing over here .. (verified in chatrooms) ~~ Or does that mean it's changed to the dots that @radp mentioned?

Comment: @dra: I changed it to the dots as radp suggested. I tested it when composing a new query. If it's not working, perhaps clear your cache?

Comment: no the throbbing dots works, it's the other throbber that doesn't. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Good stuff. I didn't even have time to install hg :)